# Getting status code 102 from coinnest.co.kr

Tags: python, rest, api

I'm trying to write a Python wrapper for a cryptocurrency exchange.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import hashlib
import hmac
import time

base_url = 'https://api.coinnest.co.kr'

class Coinnest():
def __init__(self, key, secret):
    self.key = key
    self.secret = secret

def get_balance(self):
    url = base_url + '/api/account/balance'
    nonce = str(int(time.time())*1000)
    key = hashlib.md5(self.secret).hexdigest()
    message = 'key={}&nonce={}'.format(self.key, nonce)
    signature = hmac.new(key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    payload = {'key': key, 'nonce': nonce, 'signature': signature}
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    return r.json()

coinnest = Coinnest('','')
print coinnest.get_order_history()
```

Response: `u'status': 102, u'msg': u'', u'data': u''`

According to the API response description: Code 102 means

> Parameter error. Required parameters are missing or in wrong format.

I believe I have all the required parameters of

1. key
2. nonce
3. signature.

Am I delivering the payload in the wrong location or in the wrong format? Unfortunately, their documentation is not very clear and I am a beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: have tried postman to test your request before code?

Comment: I download postman and attempted to run my request through the system.  I am unsure whether my payload falls under the authorization, header or body tab.  The O.Auth 1.0 is the most similar to the access token, token secret key but the md5 hash is not standard function.

Comment: [offtopic] but I have so many questions to coinnest.co.kr guys. Why would you use some obscure hashing algorithm? Why would you use obscure error codes instead of HTTP error codes? I feel your pain OP.[/offtopic]

Answer (score 1):

The docs are terrible, but it looks like you should be signing your message with `md5(secret)`, and set `key` to your public key, which is different from `md5(secret)`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
key = self.key
secret_md5 = hashlib.md5(self.secret).hexdigest()
signature = hmac.new(secret_md5, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
payload = OrderedDict([('key', key), ('nonce', nonce), ('signature', signature)])
```

I also recommend using an ordered dict to enforce parameter order.